# Summation Linear programming Problem

Tags: optimization, summation, linear-programming

Im trying to solve the following problem
[image: Im trying to solve the following problem]

First I write out the objective function with t=1=October,...,4=January: 
$x_t=$ no. of units produced during month t 
$i_t=$ the amount of inventory at the end of the month t 
$R_t=$ increase in prodution from t-1 to t 
$D_t=$ decrease in prodution from t-1 to t 
$f_t=$ sales forcast for month t

$min\sum_{t=1}^42R_t+0.5D_t+i_t$
$s.t$
$i_{t-1}-i_t=f_t-x_t$
$x_t-x_{t-1}=R_t-D_t$
$i_0=0$
$i_4=0$
$x_0=12000$
$x_t,i_t,R_t,D_t\ge0$
This is where I am confused as I don't know how to deal with the $x_t$ in the constraint, any help is appreciated! Thank you in andvance!
Edit:
Just to clarify since the comment is getting long, from the implicit contraint we get 4 explicit constraint:
$i_1=x_1-10000$
$i_2=x_2-16000+i_1=x_1+x_2-26000$
$i_3=x3-10000+i_2=x_1+x_2+x_3-36000$
$i_4=x_4-12000+i_3=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4-48000=0$
The only method I know of solving linear programming problem is to formulate them into the form of:
$min\ c^Tx$
$s.t$ $Ax=b$
in this case, since $x_t$ is unknown and aren't a part of the objective function, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: At the first glance your model looks o.k. So what is your question?

Comment: @callculus42 I want to solve the problem through python, however since I don't know what x_t is I cant formulate the the matrix for Ax=b

Comment: I would not formulate it in matrix form. For instance you have the constraint $i_{t-1}-i_t=f_t-x_t \quad \forall \ t\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. This is a standard formulation. I'm sure this can be implemented in python.

Comment: @callculus42 I still don't quite get what you mean? I don't see how I can solve $i_{t−1}−i_t=f_t−x_t$? Sorry if this is obvious its quite new to me

Comment: Sure. For $t=1$ the constraint is $0-i_1=f_1-x_1$. So you will obtain 4 constraints. It is hard to do it by hand, but python can do it.

Comment: @callculus42 thank you for your patience with me. I can see that and my problem was I dont know how to work out $x_1$ to $x_4$

Comment: In general there are to ways to formulate multiple constraints.You can formulate them explicit. That means for this constraint you formulate 4 different constraints t=1 to t=4. Or you can formulate it implicit : $i_{t-1}-i_t=f_t-x_t \quad \forall \ t\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ in a python code.

Comment: @callculus42 please check the edit for clarification, thank you

Comment: It seems to complicated.  The first constraint (t=1) is just $0-i_1=f_1-x_1$. Not we put $x_1$ on the LHS. $x_1-i_1=f_1$. The variables $x_1, i_1$ are part of the coefficient matrix $A$. The corresponding coefficients are $1$ and $-1$. $f_1$ is the first element in vector $\textbf b$. In total you have $4\times 4=16$ columns (variables) for matrix $A$.